# Can enumeration take advantage of non-determinism?

Tags: turing-machines, nondeterminism, enumeration

If I want to build an NDTM to enumerate a list (of all Turing machines, for example) is there a way to use non-determinism to "speed this up" or take advantage of it somehow?

What types of of r.e. sets are amenable to this--Where having multiple computational branches helps with the enumeration?

Enumeration is a pretty... sequential process.

Answer (score 0):

If a turing machine is defined as a sequence (a string, for example), then a turing machine can produce the description of a turing machine by outputting characters one-by-one.  So I would think, at a high level, if your turing machine chooses one of X possible characters to output, then non-deterministically, after outputting N characters, it can have output any turing machine with an N-length description.